# Trying to install DOCKER GPG key recieving error: Curl: option '-' is unknown

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm trying to add the docker GPG key, and I'm unable to do so because it doesn't recognize that i'm trying to pipe the GPG key into the APT KEY

I'm getting back the following error (see picture):

[image]

```js
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: there are no pictures in your question

Comment: I just added the picture sorry about that!

Comment: can you ensure that this is an actual dash ? try to remove it and add it manually

Comment: @MostafaHussein Yes sir I can confirm I wrote it out without copying and pasting it over several times.

Comment: Something strange in here, the command should contain `|` not `>` the one before `sudo`

Comment: @MostafaHussein that's just my terminal it's the right pipe.

Comment: No, the command is incorrect, it should be `gpg | sudo` but in the image `gpg > sudo`

Comment: @MostafaHussein I just changed it I pasted/typed | and it turned it into >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seems to have a Keyboard mapping issue where the pipe `|` turns into a redirect symbol `>`. It seems more related to Digital Ocean and their Console itself where your droplet is hosted - by the look of the image in the question - according to [this thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-t-type-some-symbols-on-console).

The first option is to use SSH to log into your droplet.

Your second option is to do this process on two steps:

```
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
sudo apt-key add gpg
```