# curl-ing and running a script fails with Ansible

Tags: node.js, ansible, apt

I am new to Ansible and tried to formulate the following task:

- get a setup script via curl
- run it with sudo
- afterwards, install node.js with apt

```yaml
- name: Install Node 
  become: true
  command: "curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs"
  tags: install_node
```

While the command can be run from the command line, it fails with the following error when I run it with Ansible - why is that?

```
TASK [Install Node] ***********************************************
fatal: [ai-training]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["curl", "-fsSL", "https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x", "|", "sudo", "-E", "bash", "-", "&&", "sudo", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "nodejs"], "delta": "0:00:00.012434", "end": "2022-11-01 08:24:51.941143", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2022-11-01 08:24:51.928709", "stderr": "curl: option -: is unknown\ncurl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information", "stderr_lines": ["curl: option -: is unknown", "curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Trying the alternative command with `wget` gives a similar error:

```bash
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x \
  | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

```
fatal: [ai-training]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["wget", "-qO-", "https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x", "|", "sudo", "-E", "bash", "-", "&&", "sudo", "apt-get", "install", "-y", "nodejs"], "delta": "0:00:00.007153", "end": "2022-11-01 13:06:08.298278", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2022-11-01 13:06:08.291125", "stderr": "wget: invalid option -- 'y'\nUsage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...\n\nTry `wget --help' for more options.", "stderr_lines": ["wget: invalid option -- 'y'", "Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...", "", "Try `wget --help' for more options."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: If you want to do this properly in Ansible, don't mimic the shell way to do it, but rather do it with the **purposed modules**: `apt_repository` & `apt`.

Comment: You could also use one of the existing roles achieving it: https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/nodejs

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε  Could you point to a working example for that?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I'd like to learn the proper Ansible way but also understand why working shell commands do not work when triggered by Ansible. I know how to replace the call to apt with a module call, but the issue is in the curl command.

Comment: Why it doesn't work is explained in the synopsis of the `command` module already: [_The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOSTNAME` and operations like `"*"`, `"<"`, `">"`, `"|"`, `";"` and `"&"` will not work. Use the `ansible.builtin.shell` module if you need these features._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I see. Then the remaining task for me is to replace the shell command for curl with the correct Ansible module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trial is just not the proper way to handle this kind of task in Ansible.
The script you are trying to launch is actually trying to solve some problems that Ansible **is** already solving for you, so you end up doing twice the same tasks and taking no advantage of what Ansible can bring you in terms of [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency).

I am going to stress this again, although I thing everyone in the [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) tag is going it already: do **not** let the fact that you know how to do something in the command line get in the way when you want to do something in Ansible, as this is going to bring you to nightmarish situations that you will have to refactor either way.

Here are two proper ways to do this:

1. Homemade: you will need four tasks to achieve it,

   1. install prerequisites
   2. add the GPG key to apt
   3. add the two node repositories
   4. install node

   Here, they are wrapped in a [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) to conveniently apply the `become` and the `tags` parameters to all of them at once.
   Mind that you have to [gather facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#disabling-facts), or at least the OS ones for the variable `ansible_distribution_release` to be populated.

   ```yaml
   - block:
     - apt:
         name:
           - apt-transport-https
           - gnupg2

     - apt_key:
         url: https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key

     - apt_repository:
         repo: "{{ item }}"
         update_cache: yes
       loop:
         - >-
           deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x
           {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main
         - >-
           deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x
           {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main

     - apt:
         name: nodejs

     become: true
     tags: install_node
   ```
2. Using an existing role: I would recommend the one of [Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com), as he is an active user of the Ansible community.
   So, on you controller, [install the role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/nodejs), from your terminal:

   ```bash
   ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.nodejs
   ```

   Then, just use it in a playbook:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: node

    roles:
      - role: geerlingguy.nodejs
        nodejs_version: 19.x
        nodejs_install_npm_user: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
   ```

Comment: thanks, point taken, will test. The homemade block is running without error. Surely this goes to show that the proper way is nontrivial for beginners.

Comment: Well, not if you compare it to the one-liner you where trying, indeed. But if you compare those 25 lines to the 367 lines of bash contained in the [script](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x) it replaces, then you might start to see how Ansible simplifies your work.

Comment: I am quite hopeful that it is an improvement over bash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use wget instead:

```bash
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x \
  | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Refer this:
[curl option -: is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56049600/curl-option-is-unknown)

Comment: I have tried that and I am getting a similar error, see edited question.